# Validating a summary count column with the actual records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in the User table 'total_approved_sales' that contains the count of all sales with status'approved'.

My total_approved_sales column might be off for some users, so I want to list all users who's total_approved_sales doesn't equal the sum from the sales table

```
i.e.  select count(*) from sales where userId=@userId and status='approved'
```

Table layout looks like:

```
USER
- total_approved_sales

sales
- userId
- STATUS
```

How can I query for those users who's counts are off?

Comment: Why store this information if it can be wrong? Just compute it when you actually need it and it will never be wrong.

Comment: Or if you do need to store this information, consider using an indexed view - so that SQL Server itself takes responsibility for maintaining this data and thus it cannot be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

joining to an aggregated derived table:

```
select 
    u.UserId
  , u.total_approved_sales
  , a.recount
from user u
  left join (
    select s.userid, recount = count(*)
    from sales s
    where s.status = 'approved'
    group by s.userid
  ) a
    on u.userid = a.userid
where u.total_approved_sales <> isnull(a.recount,0)
```

given the following test setup:

```
create table [user] (userid int, total_approved_sales int);
insert into [user] values (0,0),(1,1),(2,1)
create table sales (userid int, [status] varchar(32))
insert into sales values (1,'approved'),(1,'pending'),(2,'approved'),(2,'approved')
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/TPQZ17719

returns:

```
+--------+----------------------+---------+
| UserId | total_approved_sales | recount |
+--------+----------------------+---------+
|      2 |                    1 |       2 |
+--------+----------------------+---------+
```

Comment: Apologies in advance if this sounds really stupid. But since we do not know the table design of OP, and again sorry if this may sound really stupid... but should we use `FULL OUTTER JOIN` to keep both rows in the scenario that there may be missing info/mismatches?

Comment: @simon you should only need a full join if you are looking for a `userid` that exists in `sales` but not in `user`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [APPLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql) operator:

```
select *
    from [user] u
    outer apply (select count(*) from sales where userId=u.id and status='approved') sales(cnt)
    where u.total_approved_sales <> sales.cnt;
```